# Python error: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class, self

I'm brand new to Python, and I'm trying to learn how to work with classes. Does anyone know how come this is not working? Any additional tips about the keyword "self" would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
class Enemy:
    life = 3

    def attack(self):
        print('ouch!')
        self.life -= 1

    def checkLife(self):
        if self.life <= 0:
            print('I am dead')
        else:
            print(str(self.life) + "life left")


enemy1 = Enemy
enemy1.attack()
enemy1.checkLife()
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\Liam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/Liam/PycharmProjects/YouTube/first.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Liam/PycharmProjects/YouTube/first.py", line 16, in <module>
    enemy1.attack()
TypeError: attack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `enemy1 = Enemy` is not how instantiate and `Enemy` object. You've just assigned the `Enemy` class to the variable `enemy1`.

Comment: `Enemy` is the class. `Enemy()` is a new instance of the class. Set `enemy1` to the latter.

Comment: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/

Comment: Thank you guys, that worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enemy` is the class. `Enemy()` is an instance of the class `Enemy`.
You need to initialise the class,

```
enemy1 = Enemy()
enemy1.attack()
enemy1.checkLife()
```

Comment: Would you please do me a favour and tag the answer as selected, then?

Comment: Sure. It says I have to wait 7 minutes before doing so. So I'll flag it as accepted in 7 minutes.

Comment: Appreciate the support brother!!

Comment: No problem :) I went ahead and selected your answer